# How to categorize deep nested object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops, filter

I've object like this :

```
var list = [
    {
        category:'CATEGORY 1',
        label:'Item 1',
        children:[{
            category:'CATEGORY 2',
            label:'Item 1',
            children:[]
        },{
            category:'CATEGORY 2',
            label:'Item 2',
            children:[{
                category:'CATEGORY 3',
                label:'Item 1',
                children:[]
            },{
                category:'CATEGORY 3',
                label:'Item 2',
                children:[]
            }]
        }]
    },
    {
        category:'CATEGORY 1',
        label:'Item 2',
        children:[{
            category:'CATEGORY 2',
            label:'Item 3',
            children:[]
        },{
            category:'CATEGORY 2',
            label:'Item 4',
            children:[{
                category:'CATEGORY 3',
                label:'Item 2',
                children:[]
            },{
                category:'CATEGORY 3',
                label:'Item 3',
                children:[]
            }]
        }]
    }
    ]
```

I want to list down the object like in the view.

[image]

The `JSON` will go deep down to several steps, maybe 6 to 8 `children` in each node.
I am not able to find the appropriate approach to do this in `javaScript`.

Do I need to split out each category separate and loop through each object ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need a recursive function to help you out here. Take a look at this:

```
function findCategories(list) {
  list.forEach(function(item) {
    // do something with the category and label here
    console.log(item.category);

    // does this object have any children? if yes, call find categories again
    if (item.hasOwnProperty("children")) {
      findCategories(item.children);
    }
  })
}
```

This function will loop over all of your categories, and check if there is a `children` property. If there is, we will call the `findCategories()` function again and pass it the `children` array to perform the same action.

You can checkout a working example in the snippet below.

```js
var list = [
    {
        category:'CATEGORY 1',
        label:'Item 1',
        children:[{
            category:'CATEGORY 2',
            label:'Item 1',
            children:[]
        },{
            category:'CATEGORY 2',
            label:'Item 2',
            children:[{
                category:'CATEGORY 3',
                label:'Item 1',
                children:[]
            },{
                category:'CATEGORY 3',
                label:'Item 2',
                children:[]
            }]
        }]
    },
    {
        category:'CATEGORY 1',
        label:'Item 2',
        children:[{
            category:'CATEGORY 2',
            label:'Item 3',
            children:[]
        },{
            category:'CATEGORY 2',
            label:'Item 4',
            children:[{
                category:'CATEGORY 3',
                label:'Item 2',
                children:[]
            },{
                category:'CATEGORY 3',
                label:'Item 3',
                children:[]
            }]
        }]
    }
    ]

function findCategories(list) {
  list.forEach(function(item) {
    // do something with the category and label here
    console.log(item.category);

    // does this object have any children? if yes, call find categories again
    if (item.hasOwnProperty("children")) {
      findCategories(item.children);
    }
  })
}

findCategories(list)
```